# How to close Find window in a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use a `WebBrowser` control and it's find functionality:

```
    private void findToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Select();
        SendKeys.Send("^f");
    }
```

Which works fine. Only problem that there is a case when user can make `WebBrowser` unvisible to perform some other tasks:

```
webBrowser1.Visible = false;
```

But `Find` window remains visible. Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close, try this

```
        webBrowser1.Select();
        SendKeys.Send("^f");
        SendKeys.Send("{ESCAPE}");
```

There is no easy/direct way to control the Find dialog. One way to close the Find dialog is by sending "ESCAPE" to the dialog when it has focus. If you send "^f" prior to sending "ESCAPE", that will force the find dialog to get focus.

Comment: @GenZiy weird. It works for me. I have a simple form with a webbrowser control and two buttons, one to bring up the find dialog and the other to close it.