# How to close Find window in a webbrowser control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

In my program, a custom Find window appears when pressing ctrl+f.
How can i avoid the default Find window of a webbrowser control showing up?

(my question is similar to: [How to close Find window in a webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439826/how-to-close-find-window-in-a-webbrowser-control), but i am asking about wpf.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, using `e.Handled = true;`

Here is the code:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            _searchWin.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```